# Tracking Disabled Error in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, tracking, wampserver

I recently installed Wamp on a new server and when I log into phpmyadmin I get this error at the bottom of the home screen:

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] ... not OK [ Documentation ] 
> Tracking:
>   Disabled

All the other features are enabled.

I had already loaded the phpmyadmin database. I have added the

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = ‘pma_tracking’;
```

line in my config.inc.php file and I double checked that the pma_tracking table is in the phpmyadmin database. I also tried from another browser after I made the changes, but no dice.

Here's that section of my config.inc.php file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';<br/>
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';<br/>
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';<br/>
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';<br/>
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords']= 'pma_table_coords';<br/>
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages']= 'pma_pdf_pages';<br/>
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info']= 'pma_column_info';<br/>
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';<br/>
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords']= 'pma_designer_coords';<br/>
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking']= ‘pma_tracking’;
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing a table in your pmadb. As described in Documentation.html, we provide scripts/create_tables.sql which will create the missing tables (you just need to import this file).

Go to phpMyAdmin SQL and import \phpMyAdmin\scripts\create_tables.sql and run it. Or just open create_tables.sql copy everything and paste in the sql tab in phpMyAdmin and click "Go" button.
Restart the services Apache and MySQL
This should solve your problem.